# Parse shell quoted string into execv compatible argument vector

Tags: shell, ocaml, argv

suppose I have a string like the following

```sh
echo "foo" "bar\"blub""baz" "'" "\"" foo\ bar "\\" '\'' """"       Lots" "of\ whitespace
```

Now I want to execute above string as a command as if it was typed into a shell through a call to `Unix.execv`. If I didn't make any mistakes, then the shell will parse the above into the following ocaml list:

```ocaml
["echo"; "foo"; "bar\"blubbaz"; "'"; "\""; "foo bar"; "\\"; "'", "", "Lots of whitespace"]
```

Which library gets me from the original string to the parsed list?

Ultimately I want to hand the resulting list to `Unix.execvpe`. There is also `Unix.open_process_full` which is able to handle my original string by using `/bin/sh` but I discovered that my application is 16% faster when calling the external program directly without `/bin/sh`. Now I want to be able to accept more input strings including quoting and escapes.

Do I have to roll my own parser?

There exists the POSIX function `wordexp` but wrapping that function wouldn't solve my issue because `wordexp` does more than what I want (command substitution, evaluates globs, replaces the tilda and environment variables).

I only want the quoting and escapes to be resolved.

Comment: I'm not aware of a standard (as in "POSIX or ..." standard) function that does the job you want.  Which means it is likely that you'll end up rolling your own, or digging through the code of one or more shells, etc.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to split words similar to but not entirely like a shell would? How do you decide which syntactical features you want to support, and which ones you don't? Why `sh`, and not a better quoting format?

Comment: @thatotherguy the input comes from a configuration file which stores the string to be executed in a variable. That string is not supposed to contain wildcards, environment variables or the tilda. If I use `wordexp` then I cannot tell it to throw an error or otherwise refuse to parse strings that do contain these things. You ask why not a better quoting format than POSIX shell?

Comment: It seems to me that only one of the following would be true: A. the input format is out of your control and is specified to be a shell command, in which case `sh` should handle it. B. the format is out of your control and specified to be quotable but only reminiscent of sh, in which case you should write a parser for this format and not use anything designed for `sh` with all its complexity and edge cases. C. you can pick the format, in which case you can use JSON or another simple, robust one.  Pretending to accept `sh` commands and instead parsing them as something else will only cause grief

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cooked up a solution to this problem using ocamllex. Posting it here in case somebody else wants to do something similar. It should be easily extendable to include features beyond the range of currently supported escape characters and other shell features.

```
{
  exception UnknownShellEscape of string
  exception UnmatchedChar of char
  let buf_from_str str =
    let buf = Buffer.create 16 in
    Buffer.add_string buf str;
    buf
}

let safechars = [^ '"' ''' '\\' ' ' '\t']+
let space = [ ' ' '\t' ]+

rule shell_command argv = parse
 | space         { shell_command argv lexbuf }
 | safechars     { uquote argv (buf_from_str (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf)) lexbuf }
 | '\\' '"'      { uquote argv (buf_from_str "\"") lexbuf }
 | '\\' '''      { uquote argv (buf_from_str "'") lexbuf }
 | '\\' '\\'     { uquote argv (buf_from_str "\\") lexbuf }
 | '\\' ' '      { uquote argv (buf_from_str " ") lexbuf }
 | '\\' _ as c   { raise (UnknownShellEscape c) }
 | '"'           { dquote argv (Buffer.create 16) lexbuf }
 | '''           { squote argv (Buffer.create 16) lexbuf }
 | _ as c        { raise (UnmatchedChar c) }
 | eof { List.rev argv }
and uquote argv buf = parse
 | (space|eof) { shell_command ((Buffer.contents buf)::argv) lexbuf }
 | '\\' '"'    { Buffer.add_string buf "\""; uquote argv buf lexbuf }
 | '\\' '''    { Buffer.add_string buf "'"; uquote argv buf lexbuf }
 | '\\' '\\'   { Buffer.add_string buf "\\"; uquote argv buf lexbuf }
 | '\\' ' '    { Buffer.add_string buf " "; uquote argv buf lexbuf }
 | '\\' _ as c { raise (UnknownShellEscape c) }
 | '"'         { dquote argv buf lexbuf }
 | '''         { squote argv buf lexbuf }
 | safechars   { Buffer.add_string buf (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf); uquote argv buf lexbuf }
 | _ as c      { raise (UnmatchedChar c) }
and dquote argv buf = parse
 | '"' (space|eof) { shell_command ((Buffer.contents buf)::argv) lexbuf }
 | '"' '"'         { dquote argv buf lexbuf }
 | '"' '''         { squote argv buf lexbuf }
 | '"'             { uquote argv buf lexbuf }
 | '\\' '"'        { Buffer.add_string buf "\""; dquote argv buf lexbuf }
 | '\\' '\\'       { Buffer.add_string buf "\\"; dquote argv buf lexbuf }
 | '\\' _ as c     { raise (UnknownShellEscape c) }
 | [^ '"' '\\' ]+  { Buffer.add_string buf (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf); dquote argv buf lexbuf }
 | _ as c          { raise (UnmatchedChar c) }
and squote argv buf = parse
 | ''' (space|eof) { shell_command ((Buffer.contents buf)::argv) lexbuf }
 | ''' '''         { squote argv buf lexbuf }
 | ''' '"'         { dquote argv buf lexbuf }
 | '''             { uquote argv buf lexbuf }
 | [^ ''' ]+       { Buffer.add_string buf (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf); squote argv buf lexbuf }
 | _ as c          { raise (UnmatchedChar c) }

{
  let main () =
    let cin =
      if Array.length Sys.argv > 1
      then open_in Sys.argv.(1)
      else stdin
    in
    let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel cin in
    let argv = shell_command [] lexbuf in
    List.iter (Printf.printf "%s\n") argv

  let _ = Printexc.print main ()
}
```

To try it out run:

```
$ ocamllex test.mll
$ echo 'echo "foo" "bar\\"blub""baz" "'\''" "\\"" foo\\ bar '\
> '"\\\\" """"'\'''\'''\'''\''""       Lots" "of\\ whitespace' \
> | ocaml test.ml
echo
foo
bar"blubbaz
'
"
foo bar
\

Lots of whitespace
```

Success! \o/